# Firestore onSnapshot "IN" condition in batches (conditioned realtime updates)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### TL;DR

I'm working on a Chat List functionality very much like any of the big social networks have, and i'm having issues with React Native state management because a [very common problem with Firestore `onSnapshot "in"` conditions.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es_419#query_limitations)

As workaround i'm working in batches generated from a state array.`onSnapshot` makes changes to the state array based on such batches, HOWEVER i'm having trouble refreshing the batches after each change.

### Full Description

One of its complexities is that i must condition the realtime updates from Firestore in a way that it's not yet supported by Firebase:

```js
    const watchedGroups = db.collection('group').where('__name__', 'in', groupArray?.map(({ id }) => id));
        unsubscribeListener = watchedGroups.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        //...
```

(Please note that group = chat)

The problem with this approach is that [Firestore does not support a IN condition (`groupArray`) with more than 10 elements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es_419#query_limitations) and this code block will crash if the case materializes.

To solve that, i approached `groupArray` in **batches** that do not violate such constrait:

```js
  const [recentChats, setRecentChats] = useState([]);
  // ...
  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    const grupos = [...recentChats];
    if (grupos && grupos.length > 0) {
      handleRefreshSuscriptions();
      const collectionPath = db.collection('group');
      while (grupos.length) {
        const batch = grupos.splice(0, 10);
        console.log(">> QUERYING", batch?.length, batch.map(({ lastMsgForMe }) => lastMsgForMe))

        const unsuscribe = collectionPath.where(
          '__name__',
          'in',
          [...batch].map(({ id }) => id)
        ).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

          if (querySnapshot !== null) {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const validGroup = batch.find(grupo => doc.id == grupo.id);

              if (validGroup) {
                lastMsg(doc.id).then((lastM) => {

                  console.log(batch.map(({ lastMsgForMe }) => lastMsgForMe))

                  if (validGroup.lastMsgForMe !== doc.data().recentMessage.messageText) {
                    mergeChat({
                      ...validGroup,
                      messageText: doc.data().recentMessage.messageText,
                      lastMsgForMe: lastM.messageText,
                      dateMessageText: lastM.sentAt,
                      viewed: lastM.viewed
                    });
                  }
                }).catch(error => console.log(error));
              }
            })
          }
        })
        setRefreshSuscription(prevState => [...prevState].concat(unsuscribe))
      }
    }
    return () => {
      handleRefreshSuscriptions();
    }
  }, [recentChats.length]));
```

It works (almost) perfectly, every change reachs the view succesfully. However, there is an issue, here are the logs when i recieve the first update:

```json
// Initialization (12 groups shown, 2 batches)
>> QUERYING 10 ["B", "Dddffg", "Dfff", ".", null, "Hvjuvkbn", "Sdsdx", "Vuvifdfhñ", "Ibbijn", "asdasdasd"]
>> QUERYING 2 ["Veremoss", "Hjjj"]

// Reception of a message "C" that updates last message shown ("B") of first group in the list.
["B", "Dddffg", "Dfff", ".", null, "Hvjuvkbn", "Sdsdx", "Vuvifdfhñ", "Ibbijn", "asdasdasd"] //several repetitions of this log, i've erased it for simplicity
update idx 0 - B -> C
```

At this point, there isn't any noticeable issue. However, if i keep interacting with other groups and then pay attention to the logs when i recieve a message to the above shown group, i will see this:

```json
["B", "Dddffg", "Dfff", ".", null, "Hvjuvkbn", "Sdsdx", "Vuvifdfhñ", "Ibbijn", "asdasdasd"]
update idx 1 - Bbnnm -> Bbnnm // unexpected
update idx 0 - 12 -> 12 // unexpected
update idx 2 - C -> D // expected
```

Notice how the batch still shows "B" when i've already recieved "C" and "D" messages on that group. The problem repeats on other two groups, and because of that, now i get a real change and another two false positives.

The problem is that, because of how batches are generated, inside of `onSnapshot` the `batch` content is always the same. This results on as many false "updates" as groups have been updated since batch generation, per recieved message.

How can i keep the batch up-to-date inside `onSnapshot`?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that i came with is updating the batches on the go, by switching from `find` to `findIndex` and work the updates inside the `batch`

```js
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const validGroupIdx = batch.findIndex(grupo => doc.id == grupo.id);
  if (validGroupIdx !== -1) {
    lastMsg(doc.id).then((lastM) => {
      console.log(batch.map(({ lastMsgForMe }) => lastMsgForMe))
      if (batch[validGroupIdx].lastMsgForMe !== doc.data().recentMessage.messageText) {
        batch[validGroupIdx] = {
          ...batch[validGroupIdx],
          messageText: doc.data().recentMessage.messageText,
          lastMsgForMe: lastM.messageText,
          dateMessageText: lastM.sentAt,
          viewed: lastM.viewed
        }
        mergeChat(batch[validGroupIdx]);
      }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
})
```

However, to my understanding this is still suboptimal, because when i navigate to other components i will get the old batch and not the updated one, provoking the false positive at least once.

I'm wondering if i could directly handle the state in batches, instead of generating batches from it.
However, sorting and merging it would be a pain afaik.